# PDO conectart SQL con function

Tags: sql, pdo

Como puedo acomodar el siguiente código de PDO para SQL y no MySQL, ayuda, no puedo conectar, eh estado revisando foros, páginas, documentación pero no doy con la respuesta, intente con sqlsrv:Server Alquien que me oriente porfavor, aunque sea con el link de la pagina para comprender, quiero aprender
<?php

```
class Database{

private $host;
private $db;
private $user;
private $password;
private $charset;

public function __construct(){
    $this->host = 'localhost';
    $this->db = 'blog';
    $this->user = 'root';
    $this->password = '';
    $this->charset = 'utf8mb4';
}

function connect(){
    try{
        $connection = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db . ";charset=" . $this->charset;
        $options = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];
        
        $pdo = new PDO($connection, $this->user, $this->password, $options);

        return $pdo;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        print_r('Error connection: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
}

?>
```

Comment: tu cadena de conexion deberia de ser asi, `$connection =  "sqlsrv:server=" . $this->host . ";Database=" . $this->db . ";"`

Comment: Pues me quito el SQLSTATUS, pero me deja con syntax error, unexpected '$options'